# Oracle 11g installation. PATH variable appears longer than it actually is

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to install Oracle Database 11g R2 and I get an error on the prerequisite checks. It says my PATH variable is too long (>1000 characters) when it's actually just 13 characters long.

[image: The error I get]

[image: PATH variable]

What's going on? Is some part of the path variable hidden from the user? Or is it a problem with Oracle? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Run the install program as Administrator.

You are probably hitting Bug 9814589 INSTALLATION OF 11GR2 FAILS CHECKING PREREQS or similar.

It's not really a bug, just lack of administrative permissions.

Please run again install program as administrator and share results.

Note: if you click on "more details" the **Error Message:PRVF-4001** should appears

Comment: Tried running as administrator. Still the same. But error message is PRVF-3929

Answer (score 0):

If error message is PRVF-3929 then you are hitting bug Bug 9580029 (not a bug really)

Please apply this workaround and share results:

### WORKAROUND

Try to reduce the length of the PATH variable before installing the 11.2 software

If you click 'Ignore' and continue with the installation, verify that %ORACLE_HOME%\bin
has been added to the %PATH% variable (after the installation has been completed)

To silently install the 11.2 software (and ignore the prerequisite checks), run the following command:

> setup.exe -ignoreSysprereqs -ignorePrereq -silent -responseFile
>   ResponseFile

Below is the explanation of this behavior :

```
PROBLEM:
--------
OUI prerequisite check for environment variable path fails.

This test checks whether the length of the environment variable "PATH" does 
not exceed the recommended length.
Expected Value: 1023
Actual Value: 1114

PRVF-3929: Adding the Oracle binary location to the PATH environment variable 
will exceed the OS length limit of ["1023"] for the variable on the node ...

Cause: The installer needs to update the PATH environment variable to include 
the value "%ORACLE_HOME%/bin;". However, doing so will cause PATH to exceed 
the maximum allowable length that this operating systems allows.

The problem is that the check is wrong. There is no hard limit of 1023 bytes 
length for PATH. The check is a little more complex (see DIAGNOSTICS).

DIAGNOSTIC ANALYSIS:
--------------------
the max. environment variable length is 8k.

the whole environment block can be 32k in size.

For System Variables there is a limit of 1k according to 

As everybody knows, on Windows platforms the environment is combined from 
system environment + user environment. If there is a system environment 
variable with the same name as a user env. var, then the system environment 
variable overwrites the user env. var. There is one exception: PATH

PATH is combined: SYSTEM:PATH + ; + USER:PATH

For further explanations see testcase below.

WORKAROUND:
-----------
ignore the check
```

Comment: A command window opens and it says `[FATAL] [INS-10101] The given response file ResponseFile is not found.`

CAUSE: The given response file is either not accessible or do not exist
ACTION: Give a correct response file location. (Note: relative path is not supported)`

And then it gives the path where the log of this session was saved.
I tried to replace it with C:\ResponseFile but same message.

Comment: I clicked ignore in the setup window, it closed immediately, and the PATH hasn't changed.

Comment: windows 7 home premium 64bit